# Прилагательные от причастий и от глаголов

Tags: прилагательные

Как определить, образовано прилагательное от глагола или от причастия? От этого ведь зависит удвоение в суффиксе "н".

Comment: С трудом определяемые можете напомнить?

Answer (score 1):

**[Переход причастий в имена прилагательные](https://scicenter.online/russkiy-yazyik-scicenter/perehod-prichastiy-imena-98386.html)**

> Существуют слова, которые окончательно утрати­ли признаки глагола и
>   перешли в прилагат.: *смиренный, неожиданный* и т. д. Кроме того, есть
>   слова, которые в зависимости от контекста являются то причастиями, то
>   образован­ными от причастий морфолого-синтаксическим спо­собом
>   прилагат. При этом, выступая в ро­ли прилагат., такие слова часто
>   приобретают иное лексическое значение: *распущенные по плечам волосы*
>   (причастие) — *распущенный ребенок* (прила­гат.), *открытая настежь
>   дверь* (причастие) — *открытый взгляд* (прилагат.), *слегка
>   припод­нятый занавес* (причастие) — *приподнятое на­строение*
>   (прилагательное). Это же касается и крат­ких форм прилагат. и
>   причастий: *войска со­средоточены у реки* (причастие) — *взгляды
>   сосредо­точенны* (прилагат.), *девочка воспитана в детдоме*
>   (причастие) — *девушка умна и воспитан­на* (прилагат).

А чтобы не путать, одно или два "н":

в отглагольных прилагательных, образованных от глаголов НСВ с помощью суффиксов -ен-, -н-, которые не имеют приставок и зависимых слов пишется одно "н"; как только появляется приставка или зависимое слово прилагательное становится причастием (два "н").

[Отличие отглагольных прилагательных от причастий](https://russkiiyazyk.ru/chasti-rechi/glagol/prichastie/otlichit-prilagatelnoe-ot-prichastiya.html)

[Н/НН в причастиях и отглагольных прилагательных](http://gramota.ru/class/coach/tbgramota/45_106)

[Н, НН в причастиях, прилагательных, наречиях](https://obrazovaka.ru/russkiy-yazyk/n-nn-v-suffiksah-prilagatelnyh-prichastiy-i-narechiyah)

---

[Краткие формы страдательного причастия, в соответствии с правилами правописания, пишутся с одним *н* — *воспитана, воспитано, воспитаны*.](http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/3058823-vospitanny-ili-vospitany-kak-pishetsja.html)

[Краткие формы отглагольного прилагательного (и однокоренное наречие) сохраняют суффикс исходного (мотивирующего) прилагательного — *воспитанна, воспитанно, воспитанны*.](http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/3058823-vospitanny-ili-vospitany-kak-pishetsja.html)

Comment: Если прилагательное отглагольное, пишем одно "н", если прилагательное отпричастное - два "н" (в полной форме). Поэтому мне и интересно было отличить отпричастные от отглагольных. Например, слово "крашеный". Почему я не должен полагать, что оно не отпричастное?

Comment: Потому, что *крашеный* вне контекста не рассматривается. Не играет роли, отглагольное ли или отпричастное прилагательное. Как только возникают зависимые слова или приставка - два "н", причастие.

Comment: Приставка "не" считается? Нежданный, негаданный?

Comment: Приставка "не" не считается. А *нежданный, негаданный* - исключения: всегда с двумя ***н***.

Comment: Слово "крашеный" пишется с одной "н". Но есть правило, что в суффиксах "енн" в прилагательных пишется удвоенная "н". Это правило касается прилагательных, образованных от существительных?

Comment: Владимир, да не надо пытаться охватить все правила сразу! "Наш случай" - отделить отглагольное прилагательное от причастия. Прилагательное сразу становится причастием (и, стало быть, два **н**), как только появляются зависимые слова и/или приставка. И всё на этом. Про суффикс "енн" в прилагательных задавайте новый вопрос.

Comment: Вы говорите, приставка или зависимые слова. А вот слово "образованный" разве содержит приставку?

Comment: *Образованный* содержит корень, оканчивающийся на **н**. Плюс суффикс **н**. *Двойное **н** пишется в прилагательных, образованных от существительных с основой на **н** с помощью суффикса **-н-**. Примеры: глубинный, истинный.*

Comment: Правописание Н-НН в суффиксах прилагательных. **Правило I.**  Н-НН в суффиксах прилагательных, образованных от существительных. **Правило II.** Н-НН в суффиксах прилагательных, образованных от глаголов: http://21vu.ru/publ/688/25092

Comment: А по каким признакам мне следовало определить, образовано прилагательное от существительного или от глагола "образовать"?

Comment: Владимир, это очередной вопрос, задайте его отдельно.

Answer (score 1):

*Как определить, образовано прилагательное от глагола или от причастия? От этого ведь зависит удвоение в суффиксе "н".*

Вопросительного знака во втором предложении нет, следовательно, это утверждение. Но в такой форме **сей постулат неверен.**

1. **Что влияет на выбор Н или НН**

Выбор Н или НН только отчасти связан с темой способа образования прилагательных и причастий, прямой зависимости здесь не наблюдается.

**А есть ли она вообще, эта прямая зависимость?** К примеру, обычно предлагается  различать **причастия и прилагательные**, но и такое различение не решает задачи. В причастии в полной форме пишется НН, а в краткой Н (законченная повесть — повесть закончена), но  в прилагательном может писаться  Н и НН (красить — крашеный, медлить — медленный). Поэтому применяются  **общие формальные** правила для выбора Н или НН (приставки, зависимые слова, исключения всякого рода и т. д.).

2. **Словообразовательный анализ**

**А нужно ли знать способ образования слова**, может быть, это поможет при решении задачи?

Существует **два способа**: (1) прилагательное образовано непосредственно от глагола (жарить — жареный, звать — званый; (2) причастие перешло в прилагательное (образованная группа — образованная девушка).

Отглагольные прилагательные могут писаться с Н и НН, и здесь опять потребуются формальные правила. А вот отпричастные прилагательные **уже отчасти соответствуют теме вопроса**, так как их надо отличать от исходных причастий, но **только в краткой форме**: группа ***образована*** — девушка умна и ***образованна***.

Итак, только **для этой не очень многочисленной группы слов** нам потребуется словообразовательный анализ в такой форме: прилагательное образовано от причастия; в полной форме в причастии и прилагательном пишутся две буквы НН, а в краткой форме написание различается: Н в причастии и НН в прилагательном.

3. **Правило у Розенталя**

**Розенталь** не называет эти прилагательные отпричастными, но выделяет их в отдельную тему  http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=62#pp62

7. В кратких формах страдательных причастий пишется одно Н. В кратких отглагольных прилагательных (как и в отыменных) сохраняется написание НН. Отглагольные прилагательные отвечают на вопрос «каков?» («какова?», «каково?», «каковы?»). Ср.:
   Мировая общественность была ***взволнована*** сообщениями о гибели космонавтов. Игра актёра была ***проникновенна и взволнованна.***